# alt + keycode to produce dead key

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout

Coming from the US International keyboard on OS X, I would like to configure my Linux keyboard to behave as follows in `X11`:

```
[ALT] + [u] -> dead umlaut
[ALT] + [n] -> dead ~
[ALT] + [^] -> dead grave
[SHIFT] + [ALT] + [LEFT ARROW] -> [SHIFT] + [Home]
```

Comment: It's possible with XKB, but not easy. It's easier if you use AltGr instead of Alt, and if you use Alt I think that some applications would treat Alt+u as Alt+u instead of a dead key.